# How to debug non-termination

Tags: prolog, clp, clpz

I'm trying to implement `n_factors/2` predicate that works in all directions.

```
:- use_module(library(clpz)).

n_factors(N, Fs) :-
    integer(N),
    N > 1,
    primes(Ps),
    n_factors0(N, Fs, Ps),
    !.

n_factors(N, Fs) :-
    var(N),
    primes(Ps),
    N #> 1,
    above(2, N),
    n_factors0(N, Fs, Ps).

above(I, I).
above(I, N) :- I1 is I + 1, above(I1, N).

n_factors0(N, [F|Fs], [P|Ps]) :-
    N #> 1,
    F #=< N,
    P #=< N,
    (   P * P #> N ->
        F = N, Fs = []
        ;   (   N #= N1 * P ->
                F #= P, n_factors0(N1, Fs, [P|Ps])
            ;   F #> P, n_factors0(N, [F|Fs], Ps)
        )
    ).
```

When I am issuing the following query I get:

```
?- C #> 6, C #< 12, n_factors(A, [B,C]).
   C = 7, A = 14, B = 2
;  C = 7, A = 21, B = 3
;  C = 11, A = 22, B = 2
;  C = 11, A = 33, B = 3
;  C = 7, A = 35, B = 5
;  C = 7, A = 49, B = 7
;  C = 11, A = 55, B = 5
;  C = 11, A = 77, B = 7
;  C = 11, A = 121, B = 11
;
```

before the program moves on to exploring the realm of rather large numbers. So the question I've go is the following: **knowing for certain that the mathematical problem is constraint enough to terminate, how do I find the missing constraint in my program?** What I am doing right now is staring at the screen before trying to add "invariant" conditions here and there and see if they help.

---

`primes(Ps)` is a "frozen" infinite list with all prime numbers. I don't think the implementation thereof is important for this question but just in case

```
primes(Ps) :-
    Ps = [2,3|T],
    primes0(5, Ps, Ps, T),
    !.

primes0(C, [D|Ds], Ps, T) :-
    (   D * D > C ->
        T = [C|T1], C1 is C + 2, freeze(T1, primes0(C1, Ps, Ps, T1))
        ;   (   C mod D =:= 0 ->
                C1 is C + 2, primes0(C1, Ps, Ps, T)
            ;   primes0(C, Ds, Ps, T)
        )
    ).
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that clpfd hasn't been told that the list of primes is in ascending order - i.e. you're missing a clpfd constraint.

Comment: @brebs tracing is not so useful when you have attributed variables and constraints. You end up tracing the library code.

Comment: First and foremost, do not use conditionals and cuts when you are using constraints. Model your problem as constraints over integers, then do your query and look at the result to see what is still open. In some cases labeling might help, in other cases you need to figure out what constraints are still missing.

Comment: @brebs Have to agree with TA_intern that trace will not help with attributed variables.  See: [Understanding CLP(FD) Prolog code of N-queens problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53406374/1243762) and the answer for some insight that  clearly shows what happens. Yes you will have to read the entire answer to figure out what I am pointing out. That is the price one must pay for such a bad comment.

Comment: OK, trace/0 isn't helpful here, but https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=trace/1 is.

Comment: Please try to narrow down your question to concrete queries which give expected or unexpected answers.